# Bash run docker command only if user has privileges (Bash if or statement)

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to only allow a script to be run if the user is allowed docker privileges. So this means the user either needs to be in the `docker` group or be root.

I've tried to do this but it doesn't work.

```
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ] || [ $(groups | grep -c docker) -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "You must have docker privileges to use this command."
  exit 1
fi

echo "Do docker stuff"
```

Oddly, just the `[ $EUID -ne 0 ]` or the `[ $(groups | grep -c docker) -ne 1 ]` work fine by themselves but the OR condition doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You should check the return code of each command like so `echo $?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be combining them with `&&`, not `||`.

Suppose the user is in the docker group, but not root. `[ $EUID -ne 0 ]` will be true, while `[ $(groups | grep -c docker) -ne 1 ]` will be false. `||` is true if either of its operands is true, so this will make the whole condition true, and the error message will be printed.

`&&` only succeeds if *both* its operands are true, so you get the message when the user is not root *and* they're not in the docker group.

Comment: Ah! Perfect, I completely overlooked that!